# apply angular validations only after submit and not to show validations, if user removed text from text box after submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Apply angular validations only after submit and not to show validations, if user removed text from text box after submit.
my requirement is technically,
--> if user entered text it should not show any validation
--> show validations only after if user clicked on submit
&
--> after submit if user touched that text box (or) removed text from text box then validation msgs should not show

can you guys please give me solution,
fast replies are appreciated, If you provide me fiddles then i would be very thankful.

thanks in advance

Comment: `is my question is that much difficult? ` 
no one is giving replies?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are looking for, but I guess this piece of code could be useful.

It's just a basic form with its controller and some validated field.
Each field is required in this example, but as you can see no validation feedback is given to the user.

The validation pass only if the form is valid and then the submission is registered with a flag ( true/false ).
If the flag is true and the user touch one of the fields, all fields are blank again.

The Controller

```
(function(){


    var Controller = function($scope){

        // Parameters
        var isFormSubmitted = false;

        // Methods

        // Shared Methods
        $scope.checkFocus = function(){

            if(!isFormSubmitted){ 
                return;
            }

            // Reset all fields
            $scope.fields = null;

            // Do something

        }

        $scope.validate = function(){

            isFormSubmitted = true;

            // Do some validation

        };

    };

    Controller.$inject = [
        '$scope'
    ];

    app.controller('MainCtrl', Controller);


})();
```

The view

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">


   <form name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && validate()" novalidate>

        <input ng-focus="checkFocus()" ng-model="fields.username" type="text" required placeholder="Username">
        <input ng-focus="checkFocus()" ng-model="fields.password" type="password" required placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

   </form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by using a flag. Assume you have a form that contains an input. You have to set the flag `isSubmitted` to true when you clicked the submit button. and make it false when your input changes. Then show your validation message based on that flag:
Here is a hypothetical controller:

```
function appCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.isSubmitted = false;

  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.isSubmitted = true;
    //...
  }

  $scope.inputChanged = function() {
    $scope.isSubmitted = false;
  }
}
```

And this can be a part of your view:

```
  <input name="inputName" type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="inputChanged()" required="" />
  <span ng-show="form.$error.required && form.$dirty && isSubmitted">name is required</span>
```

Comment: i like the approach what you had mentioned 
but how to make isSubmitted false after clicking submit.
because html will load once and initially isSubmitted will be false
after clicking on submit isSubmitted will be true.

Comment: You can make it true after sending your data to the server or after the user started to change an input. isSubmitted must be false when the form is ready for user to fill it. Whenever it is.